# ADF Dataflow Source - SQL Server not selectable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating what should be a simple dataflow in ADF. However I am attempting to select a new dataset for SQL Server and the SQl Server option is not selectable.

Why can't I select SQL Server for my new dataset??????

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Phil Lachmann, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

If we want connect to SQL Server, we must use self-hosted integration.

Data Flow doesn't support self-hosted integration. That's why it doesn't support on-premise SQL Server as Source and Sink.

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview

HTH.